# Which adapter to use for loading content from JSON and/or database?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, baseadapter, android-cursoradapter

I've been struggling with this puzzle for a week now and I've been unable to figure this out. I can't figure out which adapter to use for this task.

My simpler goal at the moment is to build a GridView that fills up from 20 items. These items are fetched from an URL that returns JSON, and will be stored into sqlite database. The scenario is that when I launch the application, I'd download the JSON and match the JSON with database rows. Matching rows would be loaded to grid right away, while the (non-matching) new items in the JSON would be stored to database and fetched afterwards or right away.

Downloading all the content first and then launching adapter is kind of out of the question, as it takes nearly 10-15 seconds with fast connection/nexus 7 to do this (I have around 40 URLS to connect to). Hence I'm trying to split up the downloading process.

- I've tried to use **cursoradapter**, but I'm unable to instantiate any grid cells, as the database is empty when I launch the application for the first time. Hence I can't update any cells.
- I've tried to use **baseadapter**, which I've had best success so far, but it's unable to update every item during the runtime. Some of the cells don't change the text inside the cells when getView is called.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Yeah, with cursoradapter. In a sense it worked, but it kept instantiating new gridviews with each notifyDataSetChanged, so eventually the last one it instantiated had the updated content. I suppose it's not intended to work like that now that I think about it.

Comment: Thank you Rethinavel suggesting that. I looked back into the cursoradapter implementation, and managed to do it. My issue was that I wasn't replacing the cursor and I had cursorloader creating new grids.